# Is there any connection between the Vorta and the Romulans?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-movies

In *Star Trek V*, Sybok mentions Vorta Vor, the Romulan paradise or original place of creation. Assuming the perspective of the Jem'Hadar, the Vorta play a similar role: By supplying them with Ketracel White, they are the guarantors of existence and hence provide them with the prerequisite for life.

While Vorta Vor is the place of original creation, the Vorta grant the continuity of creation. Given this shared motif and the striking similarity of names, I wonder if there is any connection between the Vorta and the Romulans.

Comment: Almost certainly not. No one in their right mind would ever want to remind an audience about Star Trek V.

Comment: Still, it's part of the Star Trek canon, and hence an integral part of the universe depicted in the movies and TV shows.

Comment: This is just a coincidence. It has been clearly stated that the Romulans are just a Vulcan off-shoot, while the Vorta a Gamma quadrant species that was genetically engineered to serve the Founders.

Comment: don't forget to account for the universal translator - it could be that the translator renders the different words with similar sounding phoentics. On that line of thinking, is there any relation between the Vorta and the Horta?

Comment: @Loki I'm aware of this background information, but I've thought - and still think - that maybe I've missed something, either canon- or non-canon-information.

Comment: @NKCampbell Good idea.

Comment: Related meta question: [What's the problem with this question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11887/whats-the-problem-with-this-question)

Comment: A Vorta and a Horta locked in a shuttlecraft by Q—I wonder how that would work out?

Comment: @HamSandwich - If you dropped [Orta](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Orta), a Vorta, [Gorta](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Gorta), [Morta](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Morta), [Porta](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Porta) and a Horta in downtown [L'Chorta](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/L%27chorta), which would reach the artisan quarter first?

Comment: @Valorum Gorta seems fairly intelligent. I’d put my money on him, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't *appear* to be any relevant connection. The Changelings of the Gamma Quadrant were, until extremely recently, entirely unaware and totally disconnected from the Alpha and Beta Quadrants by more than 60,000 light years of rough terrain. It was only a quirk of fate that a wormhole appeared on the edge of their space that meant that they were able to travel freely from one place to the other.

This seems to be a case of there only being so many syllables to go round before you start repeating yourself. That being said, it's worthy of note that the word Vorta and the word Vorta(-Vor) aren't pronounced exactly the same. Vorta is *["Vort-a"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhykKuLneKI&feature=youtu.be&t=36)* (with a harsh a) and Vorta-Vor is [*"Vorrta(-vorr)"* with elongated r's](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/e2b7fbef-7d00-4433-8ede-cdaab2ad5f46).